# Core Data implementation in Swift 3 with multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have been iOS developing for 3 months now, and I am currently building a master-detail app in Xcode 8.2 with multiple view controllers (~12), utilising both tableviewcontrollers and viewcontrollers.

I have utilised the basics to get saving and fetching Core Data within a single view controller, and pushing data forward to another view controller. But that's where I am stuck. Many tutorials on and reviewing Apple's documentation many times I am still stuck on how to work with CoreData across multiple view controllers (and therefore multiple swift files).

If anyone knows of a good tutorial that covers this subject it would be greatly appreciated.

Or if you could recommend the best way to work with CoreData in this manner that would be appreciated also.

The fundamental structure of the app is:

> Project List (in Master View Controller)
>
> > Add Project (Modal form)
> >
> > Project Sections (in Master View Controller)
> >
> > > Project Sections Detail (in multiple Detail View Controllers)

The issues I am having are:

> By the time you drill down to the Project Sections Details level, the connection to the CoreData has dropped out (despite my efforts to pass data forward) and I can't populate cells/textfields/etc. with existing data
>
> Atempts to save at this point generate a new CoreData object rather than updating the existing one.

Is passing data forward and backward the way to work with CoreData? Or is there a way to create a single managed object context (ie in a super class?) and just transact with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some code and we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Please tell us the problem that you are facing. Maybe some kind os scenario in which your code is crashing. If not then it would be very difficult to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in replying. The information I was needing was quite broad so would have had to past reams of code that would have lost coherence quickly. So I ended up solving my own problem.

A) the best tutorial on Core Data on the web is this one at [TutsPlus](https://code.tutsplus.com/series/core-data-and-swift--cms-907). Covers all the basics and advanced functions, conceptually and practically. I cannot recommend it highly enough.

B) the solution to working with Core Data across multiple view controllers that I found easist to implement is to move the variables you need to access repeatedly into global variables. For example in my case:

/*-----------------------------------*/

import UIKit

import CoreData

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

// CODE

}

/*-----------------------------------*/

Hope that helps others!

PS code snippets are turned off on touchscreens, so I apologise for the formatting.